# Long running script from flask endpoint

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, uwsgi

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure this one out, hoping someone else has already encountered this and knows how to solve it :)

I'm trying to build a very simple Flask endpoint that just needs to call a long running, blocking `php` script (think `while true {...}`).  I've tried a few different methods to async launch the script, but the problem is my browser never actually receives the response back, even though the code for generating the response after running the script is executed.

I've tried using both `multiprocessing` and `threading`, neither seem to work:

```
# multiprocessing attempt
@app.route('/endpoint')
def endpoint():
  def worker():
    subprocess.Popen('nohup php script.php &', shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)

  p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
  print '111111'
  p.start()
  print '222222'
  return json.dumps({
    'success': True
  })

# threading attempt
@app.route('/endpoint')
def endpoint():
  def thread_func():
    subprocess.Popen('nohup php script.php &', shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)

  t = threading.Thread(target=thread_func)
  print '111111'
  t.start()
  print '222222'
  return json.dumps({
    'success': True
  })
```

In both scenarios I see the `111111` and `222222`, yet my browser still hangs on the response from the endpoint.  I've tried `p.daemon = True` for the process, as well as `p.terminate()` but no luck. I had hoped launching a script with nohup in a different shell and separate processs/thread would just work, but somehow Flask or uWSGI is impacted by it.

#### Update

Since this does work locally on my Mac when I start my Flask app directly with `python app.py` and hit it directly without going through my Nginx proxy and uWSGI, I'm starting to believe it may not be the code itself that is having issues.  And because my Nginx just forwards the request to uWSGI, I believe it may possibly be something there that's causing it.

Here is my ini configuration for the domain for uWSGI, which I'm running in emperor mode:

```
[uwsgi]
protocol = uwsgi
max-requests = 5000
chmod-socket = 660
master = True
vacuum = True
enable-threads = True
auto-procname = True
procname-prefix = michael-
chdir = /srv/www/mysite.com
module = app
callable = app
socket = /tmp/mysite.com.sock
```

Comment: Is it even possible in flask to run php?

Comment: yes, you just run a shell command :)

Comment: I have to say I'm a bit puzzled. I replicated your setup locally and everything looks about just fine. The only *weird* thing that happens is for the `threading` attempt to only starts the process whence called twice, otherwise the HTTP server always answers in a minimal amount of time... Have you tried `curl`?

Comment: Yes, I did try local curl as well.  Are you sure the php script you call is an infinite `while (true) {}`?

Comment: Have you tried running flask with uWSGI and at least 2 threads?

Comment: Well, no it's not an infinite... It's actually a python script that takes about 10 seconds to execute. But since you fire the process using `subprocess` in both cases, I don't see how php or python could be the reason why the server hangs...

Comment: I am really not able to replicate. I think I have tried all combinations of `nohup`, `&`, `shell=True` and so forth... Yes (I actually changed for an actual PHP script to test), I do have a `while (true)` condition in the script... But the flask server always replies in a small amount of time... How does your php script looks like? How do you launch your uWSGI server? What is your platform?

Comment: @LéopoldHoudin Platform is Ubuntu.  I have an nginx that forwards to uwsgi that's running in emperor mode -- https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Emperor.html

Comment: @JamesLim ^ see my above comment for how I run uwsgi

Comment: @LéopoldHoudin interestingly on my mac, doing a direct `python app.py` and not using uwsgi, it immediately returns as well.  So I'm leaning towards this being caused by either nginx (which I doubt because it's just proxying) or uWSGI.

Comment: Ah! Beause all tests I've been running are on my mac too, attacking uWSGI directly (no nginx). I'll check with my devops tomorrow if he can help me reproduce. Your question actually really puzzles me.

Comment: @LéopoldHoudin puzzles me as well, that's why I've been ripping my hair out :) 
 By the way I updated my question with my site's uwsgi configuration in case it helps!

Answer (score 6):

This kind of stuff is the actual and probably main use case for `Python Celery` (https://docs.celeryproject.org/). As a general rule, do not run long-running jobs that are CPU-bound in the `wsgi` process. It's tricky, it's inefficient, and most important thing, it's more complicated than setting up an *async* task in a celery worker. If you want to just prototype you can set the broker to `memory` and not using an external server, or run a single-threaded `redis` on the very same machine.

This way you can launch the task, call `task.result()` which is blocking, but it blocks in an **IO-bound fashion**, **or even better you can just return immediately by retrieving the `task_id` and build a second endpoint**  `/result?task_id=<task_id>` that checks if result is available:

```
result = AsyncResult(task_id, app=app)
if result.state == "SUCCESS":
   return result.get()
else:
   return result.state  # or do something else depending on the state
```

This way you have a non-blocking `wsgi` app that does what is best suited for: short time CPU-unbound calls that have IO calls at most with OS-level scheduling, then you can rely directly to the `wsgi` server `workers|processes|threads` or whatever you need to scale the API in whatever wsgi-server like uwsgi, gunicorn, etc. for the 99% of workloads as celery scales horizontally by increasing the number of worker processes.

Comment: I'm quite familiar with jobs but I'm trying to do this without introducing more dependencies.  But thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

This approach works for me, it calls the timeout command (sleep 10s) in the command line and lets it work in the background. It returns the response immediately.

```
@app.route('/endpoint1')
def endpoint1():
    subprocess.Popen('timeout 10', shell=True)
    return 'success1'
```

However, not testing on WSGI server, but just locally.

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact I also have no issues running locally but the challenge is running on my server with uWSGI seems to be problematic.  In case you missed it, I mentioned this in the update of my question as well as the chat thread under the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Would it be enough to use a background task? Then you only need to import `threading` e.g.

```
import threading
import ....
    
def endpoint():
    """My endpoint."""
    try:
        t = BackgroundTasks()
        t.start()
    except RuntimeError as exception:
        return f"An error occurred during endpoint: {exception}", 400
    return "successful.", 200
    return "successfully started.", 200

class BackgroundTasks(threading.Thread):
    def run(self,*args,**kwargs):
        ...do long running stuff
```